# Rendering JSON key value pairs in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm jumping from JS into React. I've searched a bit for some other threads relating to this, but they seem to be too specific, or answering a different question.

I have a local JSON file generated with a python script. It looks something like the following:
`[{"hello": 10, "world": 15}]`

How could I go about taking the keys and values from that <strike>object</strike> *JSON TEXT* and render it through a react component?

I have the file stored in a variable, like:
`'var jsonData = require('./data.json');`

Of course I can call the data through the console with a log, but if I try to display it through my render function like:
`<div>{jsonData}</div>`

I get an error noting that "Objects are not valid as a React child(...)".

What would be the proper way to import and display the key value pairs held in my JSON file?

Comment: `{'hello': 10, 'world': 15}` is not JSON.

Comment: as the error message Object is not valid React childred. You can try convert object to string and display `<div>{jsonData.toString()}</div>`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props

Comment: @RandyCasburn Can you elaborate? My understanding is that JSON objects are based on key value pairs? How is `[{'a':1, 'b':2]` not JSON? http://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html

Comment: @mochamethod What @RandyCasburn ment, I believe, is that though the formatting you used to represent the key-value pairs is valid JS, is not valid JSON, as the JSON spec explicitly forces the use of double quotes (`"`) ;)

Comment: @mochamethod - Thanks for asking. Your understanding in incorrect. What you described, and what is in your question is called an [Object Literal Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer); JSON is a notation that defines text and only text (a string). There is no such thing as a _JSON Object_. The only correct terminology is _JSON Text_. See [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). That info in JSON formatted text would be `'{"hello":10,"world":15}'` (note the double quotes.

Comment: Lol okay, my bad. Quotations weren't on my mind as much as getting the point across that I was using a key value JSON-like object. Thanks for the help. EDIT @RandyCasburn I understand that it isn't technically an object, but rather text. I also understand the quotations. However, most examples I've worked with referred to them as objects in some fashion, as well as the error code I dealt with.

Comment: So now you are better prepared to be precise. The reason some mistakenly use _JSON Object_ is because we represent JS Objects in JSON text - so it sloppily gets used. I am not the only one here to correct this. It makes interpreting questions easier when precise language is used from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conver JSON to string, in order to be display, you can use `JSON.stringify` method:

```
<div>{JSON.stringify(jsonData)}</div>
```

Of course you might want to properly format the data with HTML/CSS.

Comment: Of course, formatting will come. Thanks for this answer. It simply displays the data as a string, which is what I wanted.